# Persist code source site worpress in volume docker

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm using Docker on Windows, with the bitnami-Wordpress image, to deploy a container with a Wordpress app...

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/wordpress/
```

The dockerfile is quite simple "I clarify, I am new docker user"... configure volumes to persist both the database and the source code on my disk... the database code does persist but the Wordpress source code does not... Am I misunderstanding this? What do I need to configure? stay tuned. thank you

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:11.0
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
      - '**C:\appsSites\Bds\bdwp:/bitnami/mariadb**'
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_wordpress
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:6
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    volumes:
      - 'wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress'
      - '**C:\appsSites\sitecarwp:/bitnami/mariadb**'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=bn_wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_wordpress
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local
```

My intention is that the source code of the WordPress site is hosted in this location and the modifications I make are reflected in the app deployed by docker

`C:\appsSites\sitecarwp`

Initially I thought it was the structure of the route that I didn't understand... but the volume of the DB does work

How I can persisit the source code with docker